# Read-only or disabled the jquery tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tags

I am using this
http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/
for my tags input.

But anyone know how to set the div of tags to be read-only mode or disable it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#tags').tagsInput({
        'interactive':false
        });
```

if you want to disable the remove 'X'. use this below.

```
$('.tagsinput').find('a').remove();
```

Comment: I dislike this answer, because it modifies the DOM, and requires specific JS. Re-enabling it after being set to "readonly" doesn't work well / easily.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$('.tagsinput input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

To make it editable, you can do:

```
$('.tagsinput input').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: `prop()` is the new and better jQuery alternative to `attr()`.

Comment: I'd suggest `.prop('disabled',true)`/`.prop('disabled',false)`, for properties, or, with `attr()`: `attr('disabled',true)`/`attr('disabled',false)`.

Comment: Yes, prop() would be the better way to go.

Comment: I considered this, but the "disabled" property seemed to keep being removed by the widget. Also, this imposes some styles that must be overridden if the look of the widget changes due to browser/CSS styles applying to disabled inputs.

Comment: I have the same problem Richard Duerr.  Might have to do some JS voodoo to not allow typing

Answer (score 1):

for me running:

```
var tagsinput = $('#id-tagsinput').next();
tagsinput.removeClass('bootstrap-tagsinput');
tagsinput.find("input").remove();
tagsinput.css("padding-bottom", "10px");
```

or (is better)

```
var tagsinput = $('#id-tagsinput').next();
$('[data-role="remove"]').remove();
tagsinput.find("input").remove();
tagsinput.css("padding-bottom", "10px");
```

Comment: So many years later and this is the one that did what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I thought about this answer, but hated that it muddied up the DOM of the widget, and wasn't easily toggleable.

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw another contender  into the ring for this question. I didn't like the accepted answer, because then enabling it again after being disabled wasn't easy.

I found an easy method: use CSS.

The following CSS works great, and doesn't need JS or mucking up the widget's DOM.

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput.disabled {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput.disabled input {
    display: none;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput.disabled .badge span[data-role="remove"]{
    display: none;
}
```

You can also change the badge colors when disabled:

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput.disabled .badge {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
}
```

Then, when you want to enable/disable, simply add or remove the `disabled` CSS class form the root of this element (the one with the `bootstrap-tagsinput` CSS class).

Comment: Great idea! I am using `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-tagsinput/1.3.6/';?>jquery.tagsinput.min.js`, so the CSS is different and I had to change names, tags and attributes to make it work. But if some one needs that version, just ask for it.